# How can $\mu$ be nonzero if grand canonical density operator commutes with $\hat{H}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, chemical-potential

In the grand canonical ensemble, the equilibrium density operator is given by $$\hat{\rho}_{\rm eq}=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta\left(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N}\right)}, ~{\rm with}~ Z={\rm tr}\left[e^{-\beta\left(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N}\right)}\right].$$ Here, $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian and $\hat{N}$ is the number operator. In equilibrium, $[\hat{\rho}_{\rm eq},\hat{H}]=0$ (via quantum Liouville equation). This implies that $$\mu[\hat{H},\hat{N}]=0.$$ Therefore, either $\mu=0$ or $[\hat{H},\hat{N}]=0$. Now, for a grand canonical ensemble, the particle number is not conserved due to its contact with a particle reservoir, $$[\hat{H},\hat{N}]\neq 0,$$ the only option is $\mu=0$. This seems to imply that $\mu=0$ in a grand canonical ensemble, **always**. This is certainly false.

But I cannot find what is wrong with my logic. Please help.

Comment: posting as a comment as I'm not sure of what I'm saying: isn't the grand-canonical ensemble equivalent to replacing the Hamiltonian $H$ with the new Hamiltonian $H'=H-\mu N$, in the sense that the energy depends on the number of particles? Maybe it obeys the quantum Liouville equation, but with this other Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you incorrectly deduced that the Hamiltonian does not commute with the particle number operator.

Here is the flawed portion:

> Now, for a grand canonical ensemble, the particle number is not conserved due to its contact with a particle reservoir,
> [̂,̂]≠0.

I will explain the mistake in the above quote in two different ways. Please keep in mind that ̂ in the original question is the Hamiltonian for the system, not for the system + reservoir. This is important.

1. First way: by analogy. The mistake is the same as in the following parallel argument (note that I simply replaced "particle number" with energy/Hamiltonian in the above quote):

> Now, for a grand canonical ensemble, the energy is not conserved due to its contact with a particle (and heat) reservoir, so [̂,̂]≠0.

Of course the conclusion is absurd, the Hamiltonian commutes with itself! So the logic is flawed, and the flaw is exactly the same here as in the original quote.

2. Second way: correct analysis of the commutator. If you actually let the system evolve according to ̂ (by disconnecting it from the reservoir), then the particle number will be conserved (for the case we're discussing). As usual, if a quantity is conserved, then the corresponding operator commutes with the Hamiltonian, so [̂,̂]=0.

Comment: wait, what? Saying "the energy is not conserved due to the reservoir" doesn't change the fact that an operator must commute with itself

Comment: Exactly! Perhaps I did not make the structure of my answer clear enough. I was pointing out the mistake in the statement I quoted in two different ways: (a) parallel reasoning would lead to absurd conclusions, namely that the Hamiltonian commutes with itself; (b) my last paragraph. Does that make sense? I'll try to edit the answer a little bit to make this clearer.

Comment: Excuse the typo in my previous comment, it was supposed to be "does not commute with itself".

Answer (score 4):

Let me first note that $[H,N]=0$ is a purely mathematical relation, which can be verified for the Hamiltonian that you are working with. Derivations in (quantum) statistical mechanics textbooks often assume that it is the case, while leaving the exceptions from the rule to the chapters about superconductivity and superfluidity. Another purely mathematical fact is that $\mu$ is a number, which commutes with either $H$ or $N$.

The quantum mechanical meaning of equality $[H,N]=0$ is that the energy and the particle number can be used together as quantum numbers to label the states. (There are obviously more quantum numbers, but these two are privileged in the context of the statistical mechanics.) Switching from the canonical to the grand canonical ensemble doesn't change anything in the Hamiltonian or its states, but changes the states that we include in the statistical sum: in the canonical ensemble they all have the same $N$, whereas in the grand canonical ensemble different values of $N$ are allowed.

**In other words *non-conservation of particles* has different meaning in QM and Stat. Mech.: in the former it means that the energy states cannot be characterized by a particle number, in the latter - that we consider states with different numbers of particles (but each state in itself may have a well-defined number of particles).**

Finally, note that this is not a quantum mechanical feature: although there is no semantic confusion in the classical case, the classical Hamiltonians do conserve the number of particles, as they have a fixed number of degrees of freedom. Thus, when we work in the grand canonical ensemble, we use a different Hamiltonian for every $N$, e.g.,
$$
H_N=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\mathbf{p}_i^2}{2m}
$$

**Update in response to the bounty message**
The flawed part of the argument in the OP is indeed this:

> Now, for a grand canonical ensemble, the particle number is not conserved due to its contact with a particle reservoir, $$[\hat{H},\hat{N}]\neq 0,$$ the only option is $\mu=0$.

The eigenstates of the Hamiltonian can be characterized by quantum number $n$, corresponding to the number of particles, and other quantum numbers - describing the state of n-particle system, which I denote by $j$. Thus, we have eigenstates
$$H|j,n\rangle = \epsilon|j,n\rangle.$$
These states are also eigenstates of the particle number operator, with quantum number $n$:
$$N|j,n\rangle=n|j,n\rangle.$$
We see that the Hamiltonian and the number operator have the same eigenstates and therefore commute - one could directly verify this by calculating the matrix elements of the commutator:
$$\langle j,n|[H,N]|j',n'\rangle=0.$$

Now, in canonical ensemble we would fix the number of particles calculate averages and the partition function using the subset of the eigenstates corresponding to this number of particles, i.e., our density matrix would be
$$
\rho^{n}_{j,j'}=\frac{1}{Z_n}\langle j,n|e^{-\beta H}|j',n\rangle, Z_n=\sum_{j}\langle j,n|e^{-\beta H}|j,n\rangle=\text{tr}_n e^{-\beta H}
$$
(where $j,j'$ do not necessarily refer to the Hamiltonian eigenstates, but the only states used have the same particle number $n$.)

In the Grand canonical ensemble we would consider probabilities of finding the system in states with different numbers of particles:
$$
\rho_{j,n;j',n'}=\frac{1}{Z}\langle j,n|e^{-\beta (H-\mu N)}|j',n'\rangle,\\
Z = \sum_j\sum_n \langle j,n|e^{-\beta (H-\mu N)}|j,n\rangle=
\text{tr}e^{-\beta (H-\mu N)}=\sum_ne^{\beta\mu n}\text{tr}_n e^{-\beta H}
$$

**If we are in an eigenstate with a certain number of particles, this number would not change with time - it is *conserved*. However, in the grand canonical ensemble we have finite probability of eigenstates with different numbers of particles. Using term *conserved* to describe averaging over different states, each of which conserves the number of particles, is misleading.**

Comment: If we have many different $\hat{H}_N$, which $\hat{H}$ appears in the quantum Liouville equation for a GC ensemble?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 We work here in the occupation number representation, so we have only one Hamiltonian - otherwise the commutator $[H,N]$ wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Solidification: The Hilbert space is the direct sum of the Hilbert spaces for each $N$, hence the wave function has an extra argument $N$, and $H$ is the sum of the $H_N$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; OP says that $[\hat{\rho}_{\rm eq},\hat{H}]=0$ (because it's an equilibrium state so no time evolution of $\rho_{eq}$ demands this from the von Neumann equation) implies (just mathematically) $\mu[\hat{H},\hat{N}]=0$ which I agree with. I have not seen an answer which explicitly shows why this (simply mathematical) argument is wrong. In both cases I am interpreting $H$ as the Hamiltonian for the system+reservoir. (For @ArnoldNeumaier and Roger.)

Comment: @EE18 system+reservoir are described by a *microcanonical* ensemble. It becomes canonical or grand canonical when we consider only the system, while the properties of the reservoir are described by temperature and chemical potential (for grand canonical.) In any case, the OP is based on semantic confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You made a pretty big leap from $[\hat \rho_{eq}, \hat H]=0$ to $\mu[\hat H, \hat N]=0$. If the Hamiltonian doesn't commute with the particle number operator then $e^{\beta\left(\hat H - \mu \hat N\right)}$ is expressed through a series with a ton of non-zero commutators (see [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) or [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)).

In general, all of the nested commutators $[\hat H, \hat N]$, $[\hat H, [\hat H, \hat N]]$, $[\hat H, [\hat H, [\hat H, \hat N]]]$,  $\ldots$ can be non-vanishing and contribute to $[\hat \rho_{eq}, \hat H]$

Comment: But if they are nonvanishing then how does one achieve $[\hat \rho_{eq}, \hat H]=0$?

Comment: You have a large number of commutators, all of which can be nonvanishing, and you only require that their one specific combination vanishes. Where is the problem?