# Why can we assign both energy and particle number to each state in grand canonical emsemble?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, observables

The system in grand canonical emsemble together with the surrounding reservoir is isolated, thus have conserved particle number $N$. However, the system itself only has fixed average $\langle N\rangle$, and the quantum mechanical operator $\hat{N}$ necessarily does not commute with the Hamiltonian. Why can we assign both energy and particle number to each state?

Comment: You don't assign energy and particle number to each state, right? You just evaluate $\mathrm{Tr}[\exp [-\beta(H - \mu N)]]$ in a basis which diagonalizes at most one of them.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yes, but when evaluating it, it seems that we always simply write out $\sum_n \exp[-\beta(En-\mu N_n)]$ as if we are doing it in a basis which diagonalizes both of them?

Comment: I've only seen that done in classical stat-mech systems.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can μ
be nonzero if grand canonical density operator commutes with $\hat H$
?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596355/how-can-mu-be-nonzero-if-grand-canonical-density-operator-commutes-with-hat?rq=1) and [Does non-conservation of number of particles imply zero chemical potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88399/does-non-conservation-of-number-of-particles-imply-zero-chemical-potential?noredirect=1&lq=1).